# Best practice In sharepoint 2016 or 2013 upload and view documents to a sharepoint site

Tags: 2013, 2010, development, web-services, 2016

HI In sharepoint 2010 there is a out of the box service.asmx under layouts folder /_layouts/service.asmx,in sharepoint 2016 and 2013 where can i found this service in IIS and sharepont file system in web server?

In Sharepoint 2010 Service.asmx deployed in _layouts folder of web application and i migrated that web application in sharepoint 2016 and how i use this service to upload documents and view documents in sp 2016 farm?

Service.asmx has custom functions to deploy documents to webapplications  DropoffLibrary and  Read documents functions , for save documents i will pass siteurl,contentType,document as binary format as parameters to service save function

So in new sp 2016 farm what are the best practices to upload and view documents to a sharepoint site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN the asmx web services for SharePoint are deprecated with 2013 (although still supported in this version). It is advised to use REST or CSOM.
But, they are not removed from 2013, and they are still there in 2016.

[This Post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010/) explains the process for Sharepoint 2010, but it is still valid for 2013; it can be adapted for 2016 as well.